# CSS Transition doesnt work on mozilla

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I try to make some transition with hover animation. In opera and chrome it works ,but for Mozilla not. What I need to do!? My code is below

HTML

```
<a href="">
    <div class="teams back"></div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
 .teams{
        display: table-cell;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position:center;
        width: 360px;
        height: 370px;
        transition:1s;-webkit-transition:1s;-moz-transition:opacity 1.0s;-o-transition:1s;
    }
    #teams .back{background-image: url("link");}
    #teams .back:hover{background-image:url("link");}
```

I made the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/czu0ra9c/) for this

Comment: You are confusing IDs and classes and transitioning the wrong  properties.

Comment: @Paulie_D yea I know ,but I made JSFiddle and there my code is without mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the first `transition` statement is invalid. See: [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Syntax)

You'll have to change

```
transition: 1s;
-pre-transition: 1s;
```

to

```
transition: <property> 1s;
-pre-transition: <property> 1s;
```

Since, you've got `-moz-transition:opacity 1.0s;`, the `<property>` in your case would be `opacity`.

Comment: this doesnt work for me ,I made JSFiddle for this. On Opera, Chrome work with my code, but with mozilla I have a problem :(

Comment: Replace `opacity` with `background`. You're trying to transition the `backgound` image, not `opacity`.

Comment: I didn't get you... :(

Comment: you think like that `-moz-transition: background-image 1s;`
this doesnt work too :(

Answer (score 1):

Your transition property syntax should be like this:

```
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s;
-o-transition: opacity 1s;
transition: opacity 1s;
```

To know how transition works read [css transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: I made a JSFiddle for this question.